# PostgreSQL with nHibernate(.net, pgsql) query error

Tags: nhibernate, postgresql

I am trying to get a list of all movies from my PostgreSQL db like this:

```
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM Movie");
```

but get this error: ERROR: 42P01: relation "movies" does not exist

Here is a query that I use in pgAdminIII that works

```
SELECT 
  "Movies"."Id", 
  "Movies"."Title", 
  "Movies"."Director", 
  "Movies"."ReleaseDate"
FROM 
  public."Movies";
```

It looks like the query is not correct that is being built from nHibernate. Here is the web.config setup.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" requirePermission="false" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
</configSections>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.NpgsqlDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost;database=Movies;User ID=movie;Password=password;</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the error:

> ERROR: 42P01: relation "movies" does
>   not exist

This is lower case movies, not the upper case Movies between double quotes (!) as you use in your piece of SQL. PostgreSQL uses lower case or you have to use double quotes.

Advice: Always use lowercase for objectnames in your database.

Comment: Enclose object names in backticks (``) if you need to keep the mixed case names.

Comment: Backtics? That's MySQL-stuff and doesn't work in any other database. Use the ANSI-SQL double quotes if you want, just like the example above.